# Moving Pivit Point

Tags: modeling

im new to blender but learning quite quick...

I have a model of a car, im trying to display it in a html page as a .glb (that part is sorted)
I ultimately want to display the model and click to open doors, bonnet, boot while being able to zoom in /out and rotate.

The problem im having atm is, when im in Object Mode, everything is fine, press R and X and the boot opens as i want. When i go into Edit Mode and press R and X it open from the middle point if item. I have tried Shift S, move curser to where it should be but always goes back to middle point in edit mode.

Next Step...
Data icon add new Basic and Key1 so i can flick between movements. What do i do next, after that just save or is there more to it?

Thanks Phill.

Comment: After using Shift S to move your 3D cursor also press the DOT key to switch to 3D Cursor Pivot Point.

"Next Step" - ask one question per post on Stack Exchange, otherwise "it needs more focus".

Answer (score 0):

At top is an icon *Transform Pivot Point*, I needed to change from *Median Point* to *3D Cursor*, all fine now.